# Installation problem with SQL Server 2017 (Error 1639)

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

I've been struggling to install sql server 2017 for a few days now. I keep getting message:

> Oops... Unable to install SQL Server(setup.exe). Exit
>   code(Decimal)-2068052377 Error description:Invalid command line
>   argument.Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line
>   help.

I've tried to delete all sql folders , registry keys, uninstall everything related to SQL Server, installing as admin, cleaning and fixing the registry, rebooting,... Still cant install. Please help. Thanks in advance! I attached  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz3dz.png) and [logs](https://mega.nz/#F!J4FUCS5Q!S9lRhfgZfDafzM4AG9Py-Q)

Answer (score 1):

You could try use revoUnistaller to uninstall all SQL system, reboot your system and use some clean up app like ccleaner and try reinstall.
Have you already see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c04b654-107a-46ce-98a9-aa64068c6e28/sql-express-2017-installation-failed?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

?

Comment: RevoUninstaller did the job! Thanks :)