# Installation error . "Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help"

Tags: sql-server

My sql installation got interrupted thus corrupting my installation. And then I got this error "Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help"

Before I got this error I had a different error along the lines of cup64 or something. I deleted all files regarding sql, uninstalled it and deleted all sql entries in the registry. After I did this, that error disappeared and the progress bar progressed further and then I got this error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check for this [Installation problem with SQL Server 2017 (Error 1639)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394256/installation-problem-with-sql-server-2017-error-1639). It seems to me the same problem.